# Print the set() resulted output values into a newline

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get the python set output values printed into a newline rather into a single line list values.

Below is the code which i'm using for getting the common values between two files.

```
def print_common_members(a, b):
        """
        Given two sets, print the intersection, or "No common elements".
        """
        print((a & b) or "No common elements")

    with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
        dataset1 = set(file1)
        dataset2 = set(file2)
        print_common_members(dataset1, dataset2)
```

Below the are files i'm using to get the data..

#### file1.txt

```
teraform101
azure233
teraform221
teraform223
teraform224
```

#### file2.txt

```
teraform101
azure109
teraform223
teraform226
teraform225
azure233
```

#### Result:

```
{ 'teraform101\n', 'azure233\n', 'teraform223\n' }
```

#### Desired Result

```
teraform101
azure233
teraform223
```

Comment: Iterate and print the results.

Comment: @pylang , join method looks more appropriate than iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` to interleave a newline in the elements of a collection.

`print('\n'.join(a & b) or "No common elements")`

Also, as commented, if there is a newline in each character, you can join on  an empty string for the same results:

`print(''.join(a & b) or "No common elements")`

Or if prefer not to deal with it, you can just strip and join with a newline, using a comprehension:

`print('\n'.join(s.strip('\n') for s in a & b) or "No common element")`

Also all of this works because join returns an empty string when there is nothing to loop over:

```
In [60]: '\n'.join(set() & set())
Out[60]: ''
```

Which is `False` in python.

Comment: You should join on empty string (note newline chars are NOT stripped) and can get rid of additional inner parens.

Comment: @ Salparadise.. its should be..

` print(('\n'.join(a & b)) or "No common elements")`

Answer (score 1):

`set` has a dedicated method to find the `intersection`. Then you can iterate over the intersection and print each element.

```
def print_common_members(a, b):
    """
    Given two sets, print the intersection, or "No common elements".
    """
    inter = a.intersection(b)
    if inter:   # empty sets are Falsy, non empty sets are Truthy 
        for elt in inter:
            print(elt)
    else:
        print("No common elements")
    
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {2, 3, 4}
c = {7, 8, 9}
print_common_members(a, b)
print()
print_common_members(a, c)
```

---

#### output:

```
2
3

No common elements
```

Comment: OP already has newlines in the set elements and `&` looks nicer in my opinion.

Comment: @Reblochon,  thnx for the another way around.